# How to include pdf (getting with php script from db) into HTML

Tags: php, html, database, pdf

I want to include a pdf into html.

I´ll get the PDF File from a DB.

The PHP works fine and shows me the pdf in the Browser PDF-Reader.

```
    <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //MySQL Verbindung hier einfügen
    $mysqli = new mysqli("ip", "root", "password", "name");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die("Connection refused: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    try{
       $sql = "SELECT file FROM Master_Ordner_AMS WHERE id = 1";
       $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);        
       $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
       header('Content-type: application/pdf');

      $pdf = $row->file;   

    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "caught exception: ", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }

?>
```

If i want to add it in a simple html to custumize it, it doesnt work..

Just want a little div around it or sth. else

Comment: There must be more to it than that. That code doesn't do anything with the  `$pdf` variable after it's created.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create an iframe and display the pdf file inside the iframe. You can customize the border of the iframe using CSS.